# How to Solve this Overflow Issue In my Flutter App - almost complete now

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, overflow

I have been coding this educational app as my project using flutter, I had been testing the app on 3 different devices - 2 Emulators and 1 Physical Device, as I am heading to the completion of the Proj, I started running Emulators of different display sizes and realised that I'm getting overflow issues,

I surfed a bit about it, suggestions came up to use MediaQuery
How is it possible for me to fix the issue without manually changing the Sizes of Widgets.

Works Fine Here

[image]

Issue Occurs Here

[image]

Comment: Wrap your widgets inside of a SingleChildScrollView. That way you can scroll it if the bottom is overflowed

Comment: Consider including [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for better answer

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your problem in a superficial and more complicated way, seeing the code would be easier, but the tip would be for you to encompass the parent widget of the blue elements, `CSE, E&C, MEC, CIV, ELE, CHEM` com or `SingleChildScrollView()` widget, so it scrolling in this part of the screen if overflow occurs, then you can go up and down the screen.